# Spring: Injecting all values of String List into a bean

Tags: java, spring, java-8

I would like to inject a list values using properties file with xml configuration.

```
        <property name="headerOfFile">
            <util:list id="headerOfFileList" value-type="java.lang.String">
                <value>headerA</value>
                <value>headerB</value>
            </util:list>
        </property>
```

I would like to inject my list values through properties file using xml bean configuration.
I know that using Java we can do it that way :

```
@Value("#{'${my.list.of.header.strings}'.split(',')}") 
private List<String> headerOfFile;
```

Assuming my properties file is loaded correctly with the following:

```
my.list.of.header.strings=headerA,headerB
```

But my requirement is to do it using xml beans with properties file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring EL works in XML as well. All you need is to provide that same expression in the `value` attribute of your bean's `property`.

```
<property name="headerOfFile" value="#{'${my.list.of.header.strings}'.split(',')}">
</property>
```

This assumes you have the appropriate property resolution configuration enabled

```
<context:property-placeholder location="your_config.properties" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

---

Note that you don't need the `split` in the expression. Spring already supports converting comma separated values to lists/arrays out of the box. You can just use

```
<property name="headerOfFile" value="${my.list.of.header.strings}">
</property>
```

You'll need the `DefaultConversionService` provided by

```
<bean id="conversionService"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a setter method:

```
private List<String> headerOfFile;

@Value("${my.list.of.header.strings}")
private void setHeaderOfFile(String values) {
    this.headerOfFile = Arrays.asList(values.split(','));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's the same solution as the one on my post ! I'd like to have an alternative using xml beans.

Comment: @Momo You said: *"I would like to inject a list values using **properties file**"*. You actually said it almost verbatim twice. A file with `<property name="headerOfFile">` is not a properties file, that's an XML file. --- You also say *"But my requirement is to do it using beans"*, which makes little sense, since the class containing the `@Value` annotated member *is* a String Bean, so you *are* using beans.

Comment: @Momo *"properties file with xml configuration"* A Spring XML configuration file is not a *properties* file. Saying it 3 times doesn't make it so.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inject `List` of properties into a specific bean you can use [@ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml), which is like exactly doing right now using `xml` config and injecting `headerOfFileList` into `headerOfFile` bean

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class Config {

    private List<String> headerOfFileList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getServers() {
       return this.servers;
     }
 }
```

**application.properties**

```
my.headerOfFileList[0]=headerA
my.headerOfFileList[1]=headerB
```

**application.yml**

```
my:
    headerOfFileList:
         - headerA
         - headerB
```

Comment: Note: this works with Spring Boot only.